# Using python rolling_corr

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

--Python 2.7--

I have a DataFrame of stock prices for which I am trying to use `rolling_corr`.  The index contains the dates.  I have gotten this to work:

```
Stocks=pd.read_csv('StockPrices.csv', parse_dates=True, index_col=0)
IBM=Stocks['IBM']
GE=Stocks['GE']
roll_cor=rolling_corr(IBM, GE, window=30)

plt.plot(roll_cor)
plt.show()
```

This provides a correlation between 30 days of GE prices and the same 30 days of IBM prices, rolling it through the entire column of dates.  What I would really like to do is hold a constant 30 day window for one of the stocks (example..days 1001-1030) and correlate it to every possible 30 day window in the other stock (1-30, 2-31, 3-32, etc.).

Comment: that is cross correlation which is currently not implemented in pandas.